# How to pass a request parameter to "fr-workflow-send-submission" in "persistence-model.xml"?

Tags: orbeon

How can I pass a request parameter to "fr-workflow-send-submission" in "persistence-model.xml"?
For example if I open a form with :

.../orbeon..?myRequestParameter=myRequestParameterValue

and than pass myRequestParameter to "oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"

I tried to do the following :

```
    <xforms:model id="fr-persistence-model"....

                                  ....

            <xxforms:variable name="parameters" value="xxforms:instance('fr-parameters- instance')" as="element()"/>
            <xxforms:variable name="app" value="$parameters/app" as="xs:string"/>
            <xxforms:variable name="form" value="$parameters/form" as="xs:string"/>
            <xxforms:variable name="document" select="$parameters/document"/>
            <xxforms:variable name="mode" select="$parameters/mode"/>

                                  ....

            <xxforms:variable name="myVariable"/>

                                  ....

            <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" if="$app != '*' and $form != '*'">

                                  ....

                    <xforms:setvalue ref="$myVariable" value="xxforms:get-request-parameter('myRequestParameter')">

                                  ....

           <xforms:submission id="fr-workflow-send-submission"
                  resource="{$workflow-success-uri}?myRequestParameter={$myVariable}"
                  relevant="{xxforms:property(string-join(('oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune', $app, $form), '.'))}"
                  validate="false" method="{$workflow-success-method}"
                  serialization="{if ($workflow-success-method = 'get') then 'none' else 'application/xml'}"
                  ref="if (instance('fr-workflow-send-instance') != '') then instance('fr-workflow-send-instance') else xxforms:instance('fr-form-instance')"
                  replace="all"/>

                                  ....
```

and the variable "myVariable" is always emtpy.

I also tried to do an insert on "xforms-model-construct-done" event :

```
                                      ....
                  <xxforms:variable name="parameters" value="xxforms:instance('fr-parameters- instance')" as="element()"/>
                  <xxforms:variable name="myVariable" select="$parameters/myRequestParameter"/> 

                                      ....
//on xforms-model-construct-done
        <xforms:action>
            <xxforms:variable name="myRequestParameter-name" select="'myRequestParameter'"/>
            <xxforms:variable name="myRequestParameter-value" select="xxforms:get-request-parameter($myRequestParameter-name)"/>
            <xforms:insert context="instance('fr-parameters- instance')" origin="xxforms:element($myRequestParameter-name, $myRequestParameter-value)"/>
        </xforms:action>

                                      ....
```

but "myVariable" is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<xforms:setvalue>` on a variable, and when you define a variable, you need to also say what its value is with `<xxforms:variable name="myVariable" value="xpath"/>`, or if using a recent build (and the upcoming Orbeon Forms 4.0): `<xforms:var name="myVariable" value="xpath"/>`, as [variables](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0#The_var_element) are making their way into XForms 2.0.

Here what you want to have is an instance. Try to replace:

1. `<xxforms:variable name="myVariable"/>` with `<xforms:instance id="myInstance"><instance></xforms:instance>`
2. `$myVariable` with `instance('myInstance')`